# The Subdivision Modifier Keeps Causing My Models To Warp Inside Of Itself

Tags: modifiers

So I am having a problem where the subdivision modifier will constantly distort my models in a very odd way. The subdivision modifier causes the model to warp inside itself at the middle of my model. I will include a before and after picture of the application of the subdivision modifier. I am getting fairly annoyed with this problem so I would very much appreciate if some one could clarify why this is happening.

Thanks, Nova

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The inward pinching around the edge of your gun indicates you have internal faces that you should remove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The topology of your model is not suitable for subdivision surface. Subsurf works best with quads, and the entire side of your gun model is made up of ngons.

If you are looking for a quick way to chamfer the edge of the model, consider using a bevel modifier, which works nicely with ngons.

[image]

(Excuse the ridiculous model, hacked it together on a laptop in 30 seconds.)