# How to remove ridges from mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

There seems to be some ridges protruding from the corners that I beveled when subdividing. The beveled edge is at an angle so I not sure if that's the problem with the mesh.I know this is a simple fix but my skills is still very primitive.

Link to file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50371

[image]

After adding loop cuts ridges are still visible
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25984/the-subdivision-modifier-keeps-causing-my-models-to-warp-inside-of-itself

Comment: Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/95/26720

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>I</kbd> Insetting the top and bottom surfaces as a whole
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> Putting holding loops into the thin sides
- <kbd>K</kbd> with <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> Orthogonally cutting an extra loop through the piece,  back from the curved end

probably does enough, here, depending on how much you want to keep the flat slopes on the profile, etc.

[image]