# How do I round this shape without serious clipping issues?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, bevel

So I'm trying to create flintlock pistol, using this as a reference:

[image]

And I've gotten to this point here:

[image]

I'm happy with the overall shape of it, but I have no idea how to round it out like in the image. The grip is almost perfectly cylindrical but when I try to bevel the edge to give it that curve, it just applies the tiniest bevel ever:

[image]

It's nowhere near round enough but if it just clips horribly if it's any rounder:

[image]

I know I could use cylinders but the way I'm getting that shape is by cutting it out with boxcutter and doing that with a cylinder just won't work cause of the bend and the fact that the whole thing isn't cylindrical.

I just really don't know how to get an object like this smoothly rounded. Is there a way?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25984/the-subdivision-modifier-keeps-causing-my-models-to-warp-inside-of-itself/25995#25995

Comment: Hi, this doesn't appear to be an answer to my question at all. This guy was asking about weirdness with a subdivision surface, which I'm not using here. In fact the answer to that question is the problem in mine, they told that person to use a bevel, which bevelling is what's giving me the issue. Could you reopen the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your bevel makes faces overlap, you should better start the modeling with a simple shape like an octahedral (or a shape that fits the profile), extrude, etc, it will make the modeling much easier and the object lighter:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a perfect solution, feel a bit dumb I didn't think of it to be honest. Makes it a lot easier to take it section by section too, I was pulling my hair out thinking about how difficult this would've been otherwise, so you've probably saved a couple objects on my desk from getting thrown. Cheers!

Comment: your object seems flat on its sides so maybe make something a bit more accurate than what I've done, probably make the vertical side faces a bit longer

Comment: What I actually ended up doing was using a bunch of bezier circles and bridging the edge loops in the end. Then I just made the flat sides a little wider so I could come in and trim them down with booleans, flattening the whole side down. Pretty happy with the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is because apparently the side of your model is a N-gon - it has more vertices than 4. Before bevelling, connect the vertices on the top to the bottom with the knife tool, so you will have an edge that goes around the model. Then, bevel.

Oh, after you bevel, used the sculpt tool to make it more round. Or instead of bevel, add some loops close to where you want to be round, and in the sculpt tool, use the smooth brush on the edges to make it round.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try connecting the verts. Not really wanting to use any sculpting at all though if I can avoid it because it's going to be a game asset and I don't want to mess around with sculpting and retopology if I don't have to.

Comment: Even with everything being quads, I had the exact same problem. Really not sure why.

Comment: Try Shift + A to select everything, then M to merge, and select "By distance". Maybe there are double vertices.

Comment: Only using the smooth brush won't mess your topology! If you don't trust me, make a backup beforehand and try it out. It only messes it up if you brushes that add resolution. Specially if you have dyntopo on.

Comment: Already had auto-merge on but I tried manually merging, still ran into the same problem. Tried the smoothing brush as well, it really doesn't round it very well, if I'm not adding resolution with dyntopo, there's just not enough faces there for it to not come out looking kinda jagged and messy and the amount of loop cuts I have to add to get it looking even passable put the tri count way too high for a low-poly game asset. Plus in some places faces were clipping through each other after sculpting as well. Maybe I just suck with sculpting brushes though.

Comment: Yeah, the smoothing brush only works if you have a good chunk of geometry close to where you want to be rounded, hence why I suggested to bevel or add loops. I didn't know it was supposed to be lowpoly, I apologize. I didn't want to suggest starting over as the other answer, but that sounds like the best way to go as it's a simple shape. Last tip is to look on an add-on called LoopTools, it may help you!!